# I am having difficulty centering printed strings in my terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging

```
def CenterText(PrintVar):
    TerminalSize = shutil.get_terminal_size()
    Columns = TerminalSize[0]
    Rows = TerminalSize[1]
    StringLen = len(PrintVar)
    CenterSpaces = (Columns - StringLen)
    CenteredPrintVar = (("\n"*(int(Rows)//2))+(" "*CenterSpaces)+PrintVar)
    return (CenteredPrintVar)

ActivePrint = "You have lost the game. Better luck next time! Type 'python3.8 main.py' to play again."
UpdatedActivePrint = CenterText(ActivePrint)
print (UpdatedActivePrint)
```

This prints:

```
                 You have lost the game. Better luck time! Type 'python3.8 main.py' to play again.
```

It is even less centered in my terminal.

I am indeed just a beginner so I may be missing something obvious or just being dumb, but I would really appreciate if someone could help me figure this out, thanks in advance!

Comment: To center a string in a row, you should _surround_ it with spaces, but your code `(" "*CenterSpaces)+PrintVar` just prepends them

Comment: You need to `CenterSpaces // 2` as well, since you only want half the remaining width on the left of the text.

Comment: It seems like you want to use `rjust` function of string - `print(CenteredVar.rjust(CenterSpaces//2))`

Comment: I appreciate all the responses, thanks to them I've successfully solved the problem!